# Notification when Google Compute Engine VM is idle

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Compute Engine and would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.  I have set up a GCE VM to run commands and I have no idea how long they will run for. At the moment I am monitoring them via the VM instances dashboard, keeping an eye on the CPU graph.

Is there an easy/quick way to set up a notification for when the CPU drops below a certain level (or when the VM is idle)? I have looked into this but not sure if this should be through Stackdriver, Trace, error logging or something else. I have also installed the mobile App so happy with a mobile notification.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

James

Answer (score 2):

Howdy James and welcome to Stackoverflow.  There are a few ways to solve this puzzle.  What I think you are looking for is an alert event to occur when the CPU becomes idle.  Let us also assume that you don't want to be alerted if the CPU becomes instantaneously idle ... but rather you care if the CPU's maximum (or average) utilization over the last 5 minutes is less than a threshold.  This is where Stackdriver Metrics comes into play.  Using Stackdriver metrics, you can define an expression (average CPU utilization over the last 5 minutes < 5%) becomes true, an event will be fired.  That event could be a text message, an email, a REST call or some other story.

This now takes us into the realm of [Google Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/) which is a broad story in itself.  What I'd suggest is to spend a couple of hours studying the docs and give it a try. If you get stuck, you will find that there are Stackdriver tag categories here.

Comment: Thanks Kolban, I will take a look at that.